# How to write excel formula with c# until last row of the excel (interop)?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, uipath

I am an RPA developer and I am trying to learn how to manage "invoke code" activity which reads c# code.

I need to do some easy excel thing in excel like inserting columns, write formulas, and do "paste values"

I am new to c# and .Net coding.

I wrote the following code:

```
// Define Excel Application

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application  xlApp=new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
// Define Excel Workbook
try{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.Workbook xlWorkbook= xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path);
    
    
// Define Excel Worksheet
    
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.Worksheet xlWorksheet= (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets["EXTR"];
    
//Activate Worksheet
    xlWorksheet.Activate();
    
}
```

Now I need to write a formula until the last row of the excel.

How can I do that?
Also if you can help me with how can I copy the values from a column that has formulas and paste in other column just the values.

Tank you

Comment: Why not using UiPath mechanics like the `Read Range` activity? This activity will also activate the sheet you need. So what is your todo?

Answer (score 0):

The following articles illustrates how to deal with the Range object in Excel:

- [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-c)
- [How to automate Excel by using Visual C# to fill or to obtain data in a range by using arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-using-visual-c-fill-data)

```
      Excel.Workbooks objBooks;
      Excel.Sheets objSheets;
      Excel._Worksheet objSheet;
      Excel.Range range;

try
      {
         // Instantiate Excel and start a new workbook.
         objApp = new Excel.Application();
         objBooks = objApp.Workbooks;
         objBook = objBooks.Add( Missing.Value );
         objSheets = objBook.Worksheets;
         objSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)objSheets.get_Item(1);

//Get the range where the starting cell has the address
         //m_sStartingCell and its dimensions are m_iNumRows x m_iNumCols.
         range = objSheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);
         range = range.get_Resize(5, 5);

if (this.FillWithStrings.Checked == false)
         {
            //Create an array.
            double[,] saRet = new double[5, 5];

//Fill the array.
            for (long iRow = 0; iRow < 5; iRow++)
            {
               for (long iCol = 0; iCol < 5; iCol++)
               {
                  //Put a counter in the cell.
                  saRet[iRow, iCol] = iRow * iCol;
               }
            }

//Set the range value to the array.
            range.set_Value(Missing.Value, saRet );
         }

else
         {
            //Create an array.
            string[,] saRet = new string[5, 5];

//Fill the array.
            for (long iRow = 0; iRow < 5; iRow++)
            {
               for (long iCol = 0; iCol < 5; iCol++)
               {
                  //Put the row and column address in the cell.
                  saRet[iRow, iCol] = iRow.ToString() + "|" + iCol.ToString();
               }
            }

//Set the range value to the array.
            range.set_Value(Missing.Value, saRet );
         }

//Return control of Excel to the user.
         objApp.Visible = true;
         objApp.UserControl = true;
      }
      catch( Exception theException ) 
      {
         String errorMessage;
         errorMessage = "Error: ";
         errorMessage = String.Concat( errorMessage, theException.Message );
         errorMessage = String.Concat( errorMessage, " Line: " );
         errorMessage = String.Concat( errorMessage, theException.Source );

MessageBox.Show( errorMessage, "Error" );
      }
```

If you deal with open XML documents only you may also consider using the Open XML SDK for processing Excel files, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.